# isolated testing of backing bean that uses RequestParam without jsf pages

Tags: seam3, jboss-arquillian

I want to do a relatively simple test. The class being tested (simplified but you get the idea):

```
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class SomeController {

    @Inject
    @RequestParam("someId")
    Long someId;

    public SomeClass getSomeClass() {

        return new SomeClass(someId);
    }
}
```

And the test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class SomeControllerTest {

    @Inject
    private SomeController controller;

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() throws IOException {
    // trimmed out

    }

    @Test
    public void testNullGoalModelInjection() {
    //placeholder test so there are no errors during build

    // I am happy to use setter injection and do
    controller.setSomeId(1);

    // even better if I could get that injected in too
    assertNotNull(controller.getSomeClass());
    }

}
```

In trying, this, I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempted to inject an HttpServletRequest before it has been initialized.
```

Which makes sense.

What I am really wondering is:

Is there a way to test such a bean through Arquillian (or something else) without it involving the creation of jsf pages and then using jsfunit / warp / or some other mechanism to invoke a http request?

In other words, how can I invoke a http request through the test which will get this bean generated for me - but without it requiring jsf files and suchlike to be in place.

Thanks for any help / suggestions.

Comment: Which Container are you running this on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBossAS7 use a Arquillian Protocol that invoke the tests over JMX so there is no HttpRequest available at all.

Try changing the Protocol to use when interacting with JBossAS7 use as described here:
https://community.jboss.org/message/722871#722871

Now the tests are invoked over HTTP to a servlet, and your test should run.

Comment: Thank You. In the time it took for me to see your answer, I figured out an alternative method (no pun intended). I set up an  `@Alternative @Specializes` producer for `RequestParamProducer` and defined it `beans.xml` to be activated during testing. This works but your suggestion provides a cleaner solution with zero coupling. The `@Alternative` option does however, have the benefit that I can use a private field for the injection of a specific value and don't need a setter though.